# How to Save radio button value into SQLtable

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I want to add radio button values to my SQL table using ASP.NET MVC framework. I have a table with columns `Approachability, Speed, Quality`, and these three columns have to store the following values

```
Satisfied, Very Satisfied, Unsatisfied
```

so I am using the radio button for the values, but I don't know how to add the radio button value to the table please anyone help me.

Code that I have tried so far:

```
public class Customer
{
    [Required]
    public string Approachability { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Speed { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Quality { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult AddCustomer()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult AddCustomer([Bind] Customer cust)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        objproject.AddCustomer(cust);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(cust);
}
```

Database access:

```
public void AddCustomer(Customer cust)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spAddCustomer", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Approachability", cust.Approachability);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Speed", cust.Speed);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quality", cust.Quality);

        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Finally my view is:

```
<div class="col-md-10 offset-md-2">
     <div class="row pt-2 row-space">
        <div class="col-md-7">
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                   <tr>
                     <th></th>
                     <th>Very Satisfied</th>
                     <th>Satisfied</th>
                     <th>Unsatisfied</th>
                   </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                     <td>Approachability</td>                                                        
                     <td><input class="approachgroup" type="radio" asp-for="Approachability"name="approachgroup" value="Very Satisfied"></td>
                     <td><input class="approachgroup" type="radio" asp-for="Approachability" name="approachgroup" value="Satisfied"></td>
                     <td><input class="approachgroup" type="radio" asp-for="Approachability" name="approachgroup" value="UnSatisfied"></td>
                   </tr>
                 </tbody>
               </table>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

For example, I am including only one field radio button

Comment: Show the code you have wrote so far

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have an enum data type. You can instead use a check if you would store them as strings. IMHO, instead using an integer value would do (although it might be called 'magic value' - you can create a table and hold the values there if you wanted to).

Comment: What problem are you facing? What values do you get here: `[Bind] Customer cust` ? Also please show us your `spAddCustomer` stored procedure

Comment: spAddCustomer  stored procedure                                                                                                  `create procedure spAddCustomer(@FeedbackType varchar(50),@Approchability varchar(max),@Speed varchar(max),@Quality varchar(max),@Notes varchar(max)
)
as 
begin
insert into customersatisfaction(FeedbackType,Approchability,Speed,Quality,Notes)
values(@FeedbackType,@Approchability,@Speed,@Quality,@Notes)
end`

Comment: @PakkiyaNathan Can you add your comment to your question? Please update it with your stored procedure.

Comment: yeah I tried.But can't able to submit

Comment: @PakkiyaNathan Okay. What error are you getting when you are trying to insert the values?

Comment: `<td>Approachability</td>                                                        
                     <td><input class="approachgroup" type="radio" asp-for="Approachability"name="approachgroup" value="Very Satisfied"></td>
                     <td><input class="approachgroup" type="radio" asp-for="Approachability" name="approachgroup" value="Satisfied"></td>
                     <td><input class="approachgroup" type="radio" asp-for="Approachability" name="approachgroup" value="UnSatisfied"></td>`              I can't able to add this radio button value..It shows the validation error msg

Comment: I am getting Null value for `Approachability ,Speed,Quality`  in `customer cust`

Comment: @RahulSharma I want to store one value from these three `very satisfied,satisfied,unsatisfied` for `Approachability`,If am remove the `Required` in Model I get only Null value in my Database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so regarding your specific case while there are solutions to use `asp-for="SomeField"`, you can just match a view model field with the radio button's name field:

```
<tr>
<td>Approachability</td>                                                        
<td><input class="approachgroup" type="radio" name="Approachability" value="Very Satisfied"></td>
<td><input class="approachgroup" type="radio" name="Approachability" value="Satisfied"></td>
<td><input class="approachgroup" type="radio" name="Approachability" value="UnSatisfied"></td>
</tr>
```

When you submit your form, `Approachability` is populated with value of the checked radio button.

Comment: Thank you Rahul Sharma  .After changing the name of the radio button to `Approachability` i can able to store the value .